# Factory Method Design Pattern in Python

Tags: python

I'm studying `Factory Method Design Pattern` in Python. I understand the point of using it in principle but still some aspects got me confused when I experiment with the code.

I have made two examples, `pizza_factory_1.py` using interfaces and `pizza_factory_2.py` without interfaces:

**pizza_factory_1.py**:

```
class PizzaInterface:
    def prepare_pizza(self): pass  

class MozzarellaPizza (PizzaInterface):
    def prepare_pizza(self):
        print("Prepare Mozzarella pizza:", type(self))

class CaesarPizza (PizzaInterface):
    def prepare_pizza(self):
        print("Prepare Caesar pizza:", type(self))

class PizzaFactory:
    @staticmethod
    def get_pizza(pizza_type):
        pizza_type.prepare_pizza()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mozzarella_pizza = PizzaFactory().get_pizza(MozzarellaPizza())
    caesar_pizza = PizzaFactory().get_pizza(CaesarPizza())
```

When executing this:

```
> Prepare Mozzarella pizza: <class '__main__.MozzarellaPizza'>
> Prepare Caesar pizza: <class '__main__.CaesarPizza'>

> Process finished with exit code 0
```

**pizza_factory_2.py**:

```
class MozzarellaPizza ():
    def prepare_pizza(self):
        print("Prepare Mozzarella pizza:", type(self))

class CaesarPizza ():
    def prepare_pizza(self):
        print("Prepare Caesar pizza:", type(self))

class PizzaFactory:
    @staticmethod
    def get_pizza(pizza_type):
        pizza_type.prepare_pizza()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mozzarella_pizza = PizzaFactory().get_pizza(MozzarellaPizza())
    caesar_pizza = PizzaFactory().get_pizza(CaesarPizza())
```

When executing this:

```
> Prepare Mozzarella pizza: <class '__main__.MozzarellaPizza'>
> Prepare Caesar pizza: <class '__main__.CaesarPizza'>

> Process finished with exit code 0
```

So, the output is exactly the same. The [Design Pattern description](https://stackabuse.com/the-factory-method-design-pattern-in-python/) says the following:

> This results in increased flexibility and reuse of code because the shared functionality will not be rewritten having been inherited from the same class.

So, what's the advantage of using interfaces in this case? In `pizza_factory_2.py` example there's also no need to rewrite shared functionality. I can call `PizzaFactory.get_pizza` function and feed in any type of object.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/200647/why-is-the-factory-method-design-pattern-more-useful-than-having-classes-and-cal)

Comment: Your code is not using any sort of factory pattern. You are only demonstrating that an interface base class is less useful in python.

Comment: There's nothing in the referred link that I already doesn't know. Why do You think that my code doesn't use factory pattern? What should it look like to use it?

Comment: I shall look it up in GOF and let you know.  . .

Comment: You need to look again at the link you have in your question. The factory there takes a `str` argument and decides which exact class to instantiate.  (btw, that is not what the GOF factory method is) Your code, (ie directly inside the `if __name__ == ...`) decides which classes to instantiate which is what factories are designed to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say anything about the `Factory Method Design Pattern` because neither your code, nor the link you provide, nor your actual question is about that.

Your actual question: `"So, what's the advantage of using interfaces in this case?"` is easier to answer.

I think you have decided for yourself that the code in `pizza_factory_2.py` is better and I think your reason is that you have avoided creating `class PizzaInterface`. In my opinion this is entirely correct because you have reduced the number of classes involved. See this article by [Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BeckDesignRules.html) where `fewest elements` is mentioned.